# ItemGridView ItemClick on Windows Store App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm on windows 8 store app. In this project. I need to send the data to another page. The plan is, I have a ItemGridView in MainPage.xaml, I click the image of the news, and I need to send the ARTICLE ID of that news to next page and must create a article with that ID.

I did this windows phone 8 application with this;

```
private void MainLongListSelectorSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
            NavigationService.Navigate(
                new Uri(
                    "/DetailsPage.xaml?selectedIndex=" +
                    ((MyWebApi.Headline) MainLongListSelector.SelectedItem).ARTICLEID, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

In win store app, I try this ;

```
private void itemGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof (BasicPage1),
                ((MyWebApi.MainPageHeadline) itemGridView.SelectedItem).ARTICLEID);
}
```

And I also tried like this;

```
private void itemGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var articleid = ((MyWebApi.MainPageHeadline) itemGridView.SelectedItem).ARTICLEID;

            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof (BasicPage1), articleid);
        }
```

But I get the

> "*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*"

at the end of the line.

I could not get the value of ID with this. Is there any other suggestion any advice ?

Thank you.

**UPDATE :**

This is MainPage.xaml.cs;

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : try012.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
        private string _json = "";
        private MyWebApi.RootObject Headlines { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            const string urlt = "MyWebApiURL";
            var hWebRequestt = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlt);
            hWebRequestt.Method = "GET";
            hWebRequestt.BeginGetResponse(MainLongListSelectorLoadCompletedt, hWebRequestt);
        }

        private void MainLongListSelectorLoadCompletedt(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                _json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Headlines = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyWebApi.RootObject>(_json);
            }
            if (Headlines.MainPageHeadline.Count > 0)

                Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    itemGridView.ItemsSource = Headlines.MainPageHeadline.ToList();
                });
        }

        private void itemGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage1),((MyWebApi.MainPageHeadline)e.ClickedItem).ARTICLEID);
        }


    }
```

And this is BasicPage1.xaml.cs;

```
public sealed partial class BasicPage1 : try012.Common.LayoutAwarePage
    {
        public BasicPage1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {

        }

        protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click event won't necessary select an item in the gridview, so there is a chance your selected item is null.  Try this instead.

```
private void itemGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof (BasicPage1),
        ((MyWebApi.MainPageHeadline) e.ClickedItem).ARTICLEID);
}
```

Note the use of `e.ClickedItem` which should be the data item bound to the visual element.

Comment: thanks for the answer.I see below in visual studio when i debug below, it gets the ID but, when i go forward it says "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key" and navigates "frameState[_pageKey] = pageState;" Is it cause of next page cs code ? Can you help me about it

Comment: @KuthayGümüş Can you share the code behind for both the pages. Its kind of difficult to judge like this

Answer (score 1):

Try this and I hope it would start working

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        const string urlt = "MyWebApiURL";
        var hWebRequestt = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlt);
        hWebRequestt.Method = "GET";
        hWebRequestt.BeginGetResponse(MainLongListSelectorLoadCompletedt, hWebRequestt);
    }
```

I have added the call to the OnNavigatedTo method of LayoutAwarePage

Comment: Ya, What happens is that you are inheriting your page from LayoutAwarePage and in the OnNavigatedTo event of that page it stores navigation related information. As you were overriding the method in your page the base version of the method was not getting called and Navigation related info was not getting executed, so you were getting the error.
Please mark it as answer!:)